# how to load two colorbox in html

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am new to colorbox,  i have been given a job to integrate two html into one.

`$.colorbox` function is used in both both pages

how to solve in ambiguous problem
in one javascript the code is

```
$.colorbox({
    opacity: 1,
    speed: 500,
    fadeOut: 500,
    className: "rd",
    initialWidth: "50%",
    initialHeight: "30%",
    width: "450px",
    height: "290px",
    inline: true,
    overlayClose: false,
    escKey: false,
    href: "#productFinderPickUser",
    closeButton: false,
    onOpen: function () {
        var pickUserDiv = document.getElementById("productFinderPickUser");
        pickUserDiv.style.display = "block";

    },
    onClosed: function () {
        var pickUserDiv = document.getElementById("productFinderPickUser");
        pickUserDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

in other

```
$(this).colorbox({
    inline: true,
    className: "checker",
    opacity: 0,
    fadeOut: self.msDelay / 4,
    speed: self.msDelay / 3,
    reposition: false,
    top: "5px",
    right: "25px",
    maxHeight: "90%",
    href: "#addevent_form",
    onClosed: function () {
        $('#addevent_allday_val').prop("checked", false);
        $('#sTimeWrap').show();
        $('#eTimeWrap').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing when you combine them

Comment: once i call function $.colorbox of 1 function , it is not getting the effect of other function